# liferay programmatically read JournalArticle permission?

Tags: permissions, liferay

How can I programmatically read permissions from JournalArtikel object  without adding the portal-impl jar to my portlet?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What do you mean by reading permissions from JournalArticle ?

Comment: Do you mean to say, that you want to check if the User has some permissions for a particular `JournalArticle`? you want to do something like this: `<c:if test="<%= JournalArticlePermission.contains(permissionChecker, article, ActionKeys.UPDATE) %>">` or is it something else you want?

Comment: @PrakashK: pleae can you tell me how to access JournalArticlePermission in my portlet ? I am getting a list of all journal article. I like to check if every article has a view permission there or not.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara you can check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can check the solution on [this link](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/53021699):

```
PermissionChecker permissionChecker = themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker();
permissionChecker.hasPermission(<groupId>, <portlet-name>, <resource PK>, <action-id");
```

or a not so nice way [in this post](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/23525620):

```
PortalClassInvoker.invoke(
        false,
        "com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.permission.JournalArticlePermission",
        "check",
        new String[] {
            "com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionChecker",
            "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle",
            "java.lang.String"
        },
        permissionChecker,
        article,
        ActionKeys.VIEW);
```

or try this:

```
JournalArticlePermission.contains(permissionChecker, article, ActionKeys.UPDATE) // you can get permissionChecker from themeDisplay in your portlet
```

I have not checked if this is the same way used in Liferay 7.0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this code `PermissionChecker pc = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.getPermissionCheckerFactory().create(themeDisplay.getUser());
pc.hasPermission(scopeId, resourceName, primKey, actionId);` and it works. Is this the right way?

Comment: essentially this is the first way i listed in my answer, just that you are creating the `permissionChecker`. Though i would suggest to get the `permissionChecker` and if its not their create one.